# Fixed-sized C arrays with template parameter-dependent sizes

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working with a templated class, which I'd like to include fixed-sized data arrays whose size depends on the template parameter. A simplified example is

```
template<int D>
class Foo
{    
    private:
        int m_array[D*(D+1)];            
};
```

While variable-sized C arrays are understandably frowned upon in general, here they might be justifiable, since`D` is small and it's nice and clear how many values `m_array` holds (and that it cannot change size). My questions are

1. Is this in fact a justifiable use of variable-sized arrays in the first place?
2. Is this always bad practice, as these arrays are not universally supported by compilers?
3. Is there a clean alternative? One could use a `std::vector` and set the size in a constructor, which I'd argue makes the code less clear. Would it be preferable to use C++11's `std::array`, thus changing the relevant line in the example above to `std::array<int,D*(D+1)> m_array;` ?

Comment: 1. `m_array` is not a variable length array. So the rest of the question is moot.

Comment: He ain't asking about general variable length arrays but template parameter dependent array size.

Comment: @user1654209 OP question is definitely asking about VLAs and whether they are justifiable in this case.

Comment: @juanchopanza You're right, sorry.I was confused by a potential misuse of the term VLA by the OP while it s clear that his scenario does not use any

Comment: Perhaps I am using the wrong terminology. My question is whether this in a general acceptable design strategy and, if not, what a better alternative might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example isn't a *variable-length array*, like what exists in C99. There, the size of the array is only known at runtime.

Here, you use a compile-time constant to set the size of the array. There is no problem with doing so. Go forth and enjoy.

Comment: But, consider using `std::array<>` instead of a C-array.